# Springboot how to set value of raise click?

Tags: java

this thing actually driving me crazy, because i´am new at using springboot. How can I raise click count just only with void method? Thank you for any advice :-)

```
public void raiseClick(int linkId) {
    Optional<LinkEntity> ret;
    try
    {
        ret = linkRepository.findById(linkId);
        ret.get().setClickCount(+1); //i tried this but not success
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new DbException("Failed to raise by id link", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void raiseClick(final int linkId) {
    LinkEntity ret;
    try
    {
        ret = linkRepository.findById(linkId).orElseNull();

        if(ret != null) {
            ret.setClickCount(ret.getClickCount() + 1);
            linkRepository.save(ret);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new DbException("Failed to raise by id link", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this option, but unfortunately such an option is not available directly from the ret.

Comment: It works,but I had to change linkRepository.save(ret); to linkRepository.save(ret.get()); Thank you! :-)